# Calling stored procedures with Slick

Tags: scala, stored-procedures, slick

How do I use Slick to call a stored procedure?

I want it to be type safe / injection safe.  (ie, I don't want any SQL query strings in my code...)

According to the docs, Slick includes "Type-safe support of stored procedures" (http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.0/introduction.html)

But I do not see any example in the docs of how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a typo. It should read "Type-safe support of scalar database functions". At the moment you have to use plain SQL to call stored procedures.

Also see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/scalaquery/procedure/scalaquery/BUB2-ryR0bY/EFZGX663tRYJ

Comment: Thank you.  Submitted feature request. (https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/201)  I will implement with SQL query strings.