# generate unique sequence id per type

Tags: sql, postgresql, scala, slick

Following is a illustrative example to convey the problem statement -

say I have a Table called `Animal` which stores data for all animals types e.g. `cat`, `dog`,`cow`,`monkey` etc.

```
Animal table
id  type_id   type    json_data
```

Now business requirement is that `type_id` value should be consistent and sequential per `type`. e.g.

```
id(PK)   type_id   type   json_data
1             1    cat    
2             2    cat    
3             50   dog   
4             51   dog
5             3    cat   
6             52   dog
```

DB is postgres, Env is Scala and Slick for persistence layer

kind of sequence generator per animal type, each record should have unique generated (type) id but sequential based on the type as mentioned in the example. for all cats records type_id must be unique and sequential , same is the case with all dog records. What's the best way to create such sequential Ids w/o creating conflicts with other types of ids?

Comment: Another table called `AnimalTypes` where `type_id` is a foreign key to `AnimalTypes.id`, because that's what relational databases are for.

Comment: @m-z : just added more details to the question.please let me know if there is any confusion in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a function and call the function inside your `INSERT INTO`

```
 -- Create the function
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION last_category(in varchar(50))
   RETURNS INT AS
  $BODY$
  DECLARE
    some_input ALIAS FOR $1;
    last_category int;
  BEGIN
    select max(type_id) + 1 into last_category from animal where type=some_input;
    return last_category;
  END$BODY$
   LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
   COST 100;
  ALTER FUNCTION last_category(in varchar(50))
   OWNER TO postgres;
  COMMENT ON FUNCTION last_category(in varchar(50)) IS 'FUNCTION JUST FOR TEST';

 -- Now, call the function inside your INSERT INTO
 insert into animal values(3,last_category('cat'),'cat','');
```

Comment: @user2066049 according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18454056/calling-stored-procedures-with-slick) you have to use plain query to do this. I haven't used Slick before, but I think the algo will be the same if you do that in Slick way